# Can't make type classes work in Lean

Tags: formal-methods, lean

I'm having trouble understanding how to trigger the use of type classes by Lean. Here is an attempt at a small example:

```
section the_section
structure toto [class] (A : Type) := (rel : A → A → Prop) (Hall : ∀ a, rel a a)

definition P A := exists (a : A), forall x, x = a
parameter A : Type
variable HA : P A

lemma T [instance] {B : Type} [HPB : P B] : toto B := toto.mk (λ x y, x = y) (λ x, rfl)

include HA
example : toto A := _
-- this gives the error: don't know how to infer placeholder toto A

end the_section
```

The point is I would like Lean to see that it can use HA to deduce toto A from lemma T. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, I had to post the question to find the answer. Hope this helps other people.

P needs to be a class, so we actually need to change

```
definition P A := exists (a : A), forall x, x = a
```

to

```
definition P [class] A := exists (a : A), forall x, x = a
```